# Obtaining valid win probabilities from contest data using a binomial model

Tags: probability, logistic, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, lsmeans

I conducted an enclosure experiment on lizards where I recorded contest outcome for every male-male combat. We had three morphs of lizards (o, w, y) in each enclosure.
I am interested in obtaining probabilities of winning of each morph against every other morph (e.g. o beats y, y beats w, w beats y) and test whether they significantly differ from even odds (0.5). To do so, I dealt with pseudo-replication (5-3 wins between lizards A and B turns into 1-0) and fit three logistic mixed models, one for each morph. Each of the datasets looks like this:

```
        Enclosure    id1     id2  morph1  morph2  outcome
         e1         e1m4    e1m3      w       o       1
         e2         e2m4    e2m1      w       y       0
         e3         e3m4    e1m3      w       y       1
         e3         e1m6    e3m1      w       o       1
         .          .         .       .       .       .
         .          .         .       .       .       .
```

In which morph1 is always "w", "o", or "y". I then use the following model

```
q <- glmer(outcome ~ morph2 + (1 | id1) + (1 | id2) + (1 | Encl), data = wbin,
           family = binomial(), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
           nAGQ = 1)
```

And then use **emmeans** to try to extract the probabilities of winning against the other two morphs.

```
wbin.emm <- emmeans(q, "morph2", type = "response")
wbin.emm
```

For each of the three models this yields very odd results (e.g. in the white morph model I obtain extremely small probabilities.

```
              morph2     prob       SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
              o      1.19e-07 6.54e-07 Inf  2.49e-12   0.00565
              y      2.53e-05 8.21e-05 Inf  4.35e-08   0.01450
```

These results make no sense to me because just from checking the average probabilities with summarySE (i.e. neglecting the lizard's identity) we can see that no morph combination is strongly biased in its outcome.

```
tgc <- summarySE(wbin, measurevar = "outcome", groupvars = "morph2",
                 na.rm = TRUE) 
tgc

         morph2  N   outcome        sd         se        ci
       1      o 51 0.4901961 0.5048782 0.07069708 0.1419993
       2      y 50 0.5600000 0.5014265 0.07091242 0.1425038
```

I would gladly upload some of my data if requested (I couldn't find how to do it).

```
      Edit: results from summary

      Random effects:
      Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
      id2    (Intercept)  149.7   12.24   
      id1    (Intercept) 1001.5   31.65   
      Encl   (Intercept)  142.4   11.93   
      Number of obs: 101, groups:  id2, 51; id1, 29; Encl, 10
```

Comment: What you shoe for `wbin.emm` does not appear to be result from `emmeans()‘. The column headings and order thereof differ from anything `emmeans()` produces. So I can’t believe you are showing the actual resultx you obtained, unless there is some package besides **emmeans** that has a function by that name.

Comment: You are right, @rvl. Thanks for pointing that out. There were the results from: back.emmeans(marginal, transform = c("logit"), base = exp(1),
             add = 0, ord = FALSE, decreasing = TRUE)

Comment: I have no idea what that function is. Never heard of it.

Comment: When you post a question on SO, there is an understanding that the code you show is what was actually used to produce the output shown. To do otherwise, which is the case here, is misleading. For that reason I am initiating a hold on this question.

Comment: It was a non-intentioanl error when copying the results from my script, I am sorry for the inconvenience. I look forward to correct any other issues I have failed to see.

Comment: The appropriate remedy is to correct the question by editing it.

Comment: @rvl I have changed the output of the emmeans. It is now the correct one.

Comment: What is the output of `summary(q)`, more specifically the variances of the random effects for `id1`, `id2` and `Encl`?

Answer (score 2):

Note that from a mixed model the fixed effects coefficients and the probabilities you calculate from them have an interpretation conditional on the random effects. This will be different than the observed probabilities, especially as the variance of the random effects increases. In particular, in the case of the mixed-effects logistic regression with only one random intercept, the relation between the marginal and conditional log odds ratios is:

$$\beta^M = \frac{\beta^C}{\sqrt{1 + 0.346 \times \sigma_b^2}},$$

where $\sigma_b^2$ is the variance of the random intercepts.

Comment: I have added the variance for the random effects to the post. Could you guide me through how to obtain the probabilities by using the formula you gave me? Does that mean that the prob of "o" winning is = 6.54e-07/((1+0.346x(149.7+1001.5+142.4)^(1/2)). Is there a way I could obtain a confidence interval for that?

Comment: I found out about GLMMadaptive and tried to fit the model there to obtain marginalized coefficients but I dont know how to fit two different random factors. Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Currently **GLMMadaptive** only supports a singel grouping factor.